# Using Google SMTP

Tags: smtp

I am using Google SMTP for sending out emails from my app.
The mails go out fine. But the from address is always set to the verification email.
Is this by design?

```
  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
  smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myacc@gmail.com", "mypwd");
  smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

  MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
  smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

  smtpClient.Port = 587;

  message.From = new MailAddress("guest_email@yahoo.com", "GuestName");
```

This last line should send the mail on behalf of the guest email.

Somehow I always see this is set to "myacc@gmail.com", not "guest_email@yahoo.com"

Is this by design or Google won't allow to set it that way?

How can I do what I said above?

Basically, my guest sends mail to a number of other people. I need my guest to know which emails has bounced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to verify the account you want to send mail from at gmail.com. You can find the setting at Settings -> Accounts and Import -> Send mail as.

Comment: There are large number of guests. Do I have to verify all of them?

Comment: I mean, it is not just one guest who can send email. I have 1000+ users who can send email to other people and all of those 1000+ has different emails.

Comment: In that case, you should simply not use the GMail SMTP server. Because yes, you have to verify all of them.

Comment: Is it possible to forward the bounced emails to a specific email (guest who sent it) programmatic way through goggle SMTP? I guess not.

Comment: Everything is possible, but that doesn't make it the best solution. I really recommend finding an alternative SMTP server. You could easily install your own SMTP server to do this work for you.

Comment: Yes. That is my ultimate goal. But I wanted to test final code with google smtp!